# How to decode local json list to model objects?

Tags: flutter

Flutter newbie here. I am having a hard time trying to decode a local json list to model objects.

I am successful so far with showing what I want to show with something like:
myData[index]['id']
myData[index]['name']

But I would like to use a model object that I already created like:
rule.id
rule.name

And eventually passing the rule object through the onTap event.

This is the code I used to load json:         future:DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/rule.json'),

This is the code inside a FutureBuilder.

```
        var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data);

        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.people),
                title: Text(myData[index]['id']),
                subtitle: Text(myData[index]['name']),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                onTap: () => RuleDetailPage.show(context),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: myData == null ? 0 : myData.length,
        );
      },
    )
);
```

The fromJson method looks like this:

factory Rule.fromJson(Map json) {
    return Rule(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
     );
  }
}

Comment: Hi, it's not really clear what you're asking for. This seems like a very broad question in fact, as there's probably more than one way to do the kind of thing you mention. There is a huge amount of technical info online to get started with this kind of thing. Suggest you try to research the topic, try out an approach you want to use, and post here if you hit a specific issue that an internet search can't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting a list of JSON objects. Just cast the result of `decode` to a list, and then map each JSON object into a Rule by passing it into your factory.

Like so:

```dart
var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data) as List;

List<Rule> rules = list.map((item) {
  return Rule.fromJson(item);
}).toList();

return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {i
    Rule currentRule = rules[index];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.people),
        title: Text(currentRule.id),
        subtitle: Text(currentRule.name),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
        onTap: () => RuleDetailPage.show(context),
      ),
    );
  },
  itemCount: myData == null ? 0 : rules.length,
);
```

Comment: This works the way I want it with a couple of minor changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a json parser: https://app.quicktype.io/
This will allow you to create a model class, and then you will be able to call your objects in the way that you suggest.

Comment: That's a great resource. Thanks for posting it!

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. I was able to create the class but I didn't know how to parse the array and the parser actually provides the code for it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you already did most of the job ;-)

`json.decode(snapshot.data)` return a Json object which can be a `Map<String, dynamic>` or a `List<dynamic>` regarding if the root node of your json is an object or an array.

It seems that you already implemented the `fromJson` factory method which is the way to go except if you want to try a parsing library as mentioned by @code-poet

So just assemble all parts of your code: `var rules = Rule.fromJson(json.decode(snapshot.data));` et voilà !

If your `snapshot.data` contains an array of `Rule` then as mentioned `json.decode` returns a list and you must write: `json.map((j) => Rule.fromJson(j)).toList();`

Comment: Yes it is an array. I totally missed the .toList(). Thanks.